# How to add Rate Yo into the database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add the Rate Yo into the database. but I couldn't I always the get the error of

> Undefined index: rating in C:\xampp\htdocs\bill\bill\add_rate.php on
>   line 57

I tried the code which I attached below.

**Form**

```
<form action="add_rate.php" method="post">

    <div class="rateyo" id= "rating"
         data-rateyo-rating="4"
         data-rateyo-num-stars="5"
         data-rateyo-score="3"></div>
    <span class='score'>0</span>
    <span class='result'>0</span>
    </div>

    <div><input type="submit" name="add"> </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
        $(".rateyo").rateYo().on("rateyo.change", function (e, data) {
            var rating = data.rating;
            $(this).parent().find('.score').text('score :'+ 
        $(this).attr('data-rateyo-score'));
            $(this).parent().find('.result').text('rating :'+ rating);
        });
    });
```

**php code**

```
require 'db_connection.php';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    $rating = $_POST["rating"];
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
    if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ratee (rate) VALUES ('$rating')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "New Rate addedddd successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: no sir i didn't use ajax just php only

Comment: can you check now sir.   <div class="rateyo" id= "rating"

Comment: yes sir. ................ score added into the database

Comment: i attached the image above sir I need to  add the rating value into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form code and jquery code like below:

```
<form action="add_rate.php" method="post">

    <div class="rateyo" id= "rating"
         data-rateyo-rating="4"
         data-rateyo-num-stars="5"
         data-rateyo-score="3"></div>
    <span class='score'>0</span>
    <span class='result'>0</span>
    <input type="text" name="rating">
    </div>

    <div><input type="submit" name="add"> </div> <!-- added hidden field with name rating
</form>
```

jquery code:-

```
$(function () {
    $(".rateyo").rateYo().on("rateyo.change", function (e, data) {
        var rating = data.rating;
        $(this).parent().find('.score').text('score :'+ $(this).attr('data-rateyo-score'));
        $(this).parent().find('.result').text('rating :'+ rating);
        $(this).parent().find('input[name=rating]').val(rating); //add rating value to input field
    });
});
```

Change php code a bit:-

```
if (!empty($_POST["rating"]))
{
    //rest of your code
}else{
   die('ratings required');
}
```

Note:- You php code is wide open for SQL INJECTION, so use `prepared statements` to prevent from it.

Comment: sir record added value became 0 sir

Comment: sir now record added but it added star only 3. i need add the rating sir.above image like that

Comment: thank you sir it is helpful for me............................